# Having issues retrieving data from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to figure out how to connect and fetch data from a database using PDO, I have been using mysqli but figure PDO is the way to go now a days.

Here is my code, looks like I can connect but I am not able to grab any data.

```
   <?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pw = "";
$dbName = "test";

$numberID = 1;

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $user, $pw);

if ($pdo){
    echo "Connected";

    $smt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT from sample WHERE id=:ID");
    $smt->bindParam(":ID", $numberID);

    if($smt->execute()){
        $rows=$smt->fetchAll();
        print_r($rows);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your dsn, you didn't use the database `$dbName`

Comment: There must be a * after SELECT..

Answer (score 2):

There is syntax error in your query. You are missing `*` or specific column names which you want to select

```
$smt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * from sample WHERE id=:ID");
```

and you have not used database name in your connection. Try to use this

```
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbName, $user, $pw);
```

Comment: Ok I tried that, I dont get any errors but I dont retrieve data either.

Comment: pls check in your table if row exists with id 1 and you have not used database name in connection

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the column names or * after the `SELECT` and use the database while creating the `PDO` object. The working code is provided

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "";
    $pw = "";
    $dbName = "test";
    $numberID = 1;
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbName, $user, $pw);

    if ($pdo){
        echo "Connected";    
        $smt=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE id=:ID");
        $smt->bindParam(":ID", $numberID);    
        if($smt->execute()){
            $rows=$smt->fetchAll();
            print_r($rows);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really silly, but have you confirmed PDO is installed?  Check the error logs to see if it's barking about a missing pdo driver.